# C++: Order of declaration in public and private

Tags: c++

I am unsure about the order of declaration in my class. My compiler says `error: "Foo" was not declared in this scope`. If I change the order of `public` and `private` parts of the class, I end up with the same error. Also, if I want to use the `getFoo()`, and I am including my header file, the struct Foo type is not visible because it's private. But if I put it in public scope again, then public would have to come before private because otherwise the declaration of `myFoo` of type `Foo` can't happen since `Foo` was not decalred yet.
I am confused here... thanks for your help!

```
/*MyClass.h*/

class MyClass
{


private:

 struct Foo{
  int bar;
 };

Foo myFoo;


public:
 Foo getFoo(){ return myFoo;}

};
```

Comment: Why doesn't your class have a name

Comment: Please show some complete code that reproduces the error. There's nothing wrong with what you have shown. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/hZCRtm).

Comment: @juanchopanza: says g++, "foo.cpp:2:1: error: an anonymous struct cannot have function members"

Comment: **-1 for editing the question text after the answers and posting garbage before**

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is not anonymous anymore. It has been given a name, completely changing the nature of the question. http://ideone.com/hZCRtm

Comment: rolled back to original version because answers had already been posted, whose meaning the edit changed

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oh no, that invalidates my answer. Never mind, serves me right for answering this kind of question :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: sorry he he :)

Comment: Sorry, missing the classname was a typo when copying the code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I noticed the remaining questions attempt to address the "fixed" code sample, so I rolled forward to revision 2.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with public or private. Your inner type has to be defined before it is used:

```
struct Foo
{
  Bar bar() { return Bar(); } // ERROR
  struct Bar {};
};

struct Foo
{
  struct Bar {};
  Bar bar() { return Bar(); } // OK
};
```

**Note**: there has been some confusion concerning the accessibility of a `private` type. THe type is accessible outside of its class, it just cannot be named. So, this code that accesses the private type is completely legal:

```
class Foo
{
    struct Bar { 
        void do_stuff() const {}
    };

public:
    Bar bar() { return Bar(); } // OK
};
int main() 
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar().do_stuff(); // use temporary Bar object

    // In C++11, you can even make a named instance
    auto b = f.bar();   // instantiate a Bar object called b
    b.do_stuff();       // use it
}
```

Comment: Is there a logical explanation for allowing such access to private type?.. What about encapsulation?

Answer (score -1):

Your struct Foo should be public otherwise getFoo getter will not work as Foo is accessible only inside your class

Comment: @TonyD But `auto f = x.getFoo();` would work. The `private` is not the issue here.